# Change input box: input area with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, input, area

So, I have a box that I want to use as my search box/input box. Although when I type on it, I can type on the whole image.

What I want to do, is to be only able to type in the white space of the image? Would I add padding to it?

This is my CSS:

```
input.searchbox {
background-color: #fff;
background:url(search.png) no-repeat;
width:250px;
height:41px;
border:none;
font-size:20px;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="searchbox" size="20" value="{Q}">
```

Also, how would I change the text size within the box?

Answer (score 1):

your image is a **background** image. so the text will write over it if necessary.

try putting in a seperate image with some margin between that and the text.

Comment: So just add an image with maybe the background of the search box, and put the white space image on top of the other image?

Comment: without knowing what your image looks like, that sounds about right. a background image, as far as i know, does not interact with other elements. it's like a background color, it won't move out of the way for your text/element

Comment: So, dumb question here. How would I add put the input "image" onto the the background image? I'm sorry if that sounds stupid, I'm just not very fluent with CSS as of yet. I would just add the background image like you said, but how do I "line" it up on top of that background image with my input box?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your image (text location, what the text is) I used a table to hold the input (with image) and then in a seperate column had the submit button with a matching image next to it.

IMHO it really depends on the image that your using and how you are trying to match it up with the input field.